# Shift all data to one table to another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables A and B both table are same, if I will insert today some values on table A and I want to all inserted table A data automatic insert on table B after 2 days. for example today is 15 June 2013 and  all table A data shifted automatic on 17 June 2013.

Please give me any script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `INSERT INTO B (SELECT * FROM A)`

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add a timestamp field to your rows in Table A, then you can do this:

```
insert into b (select * from A where datediff(curdate(), postdate)>=2)
```

where postdate is your timestamp.

To automate this you can use the mySQL event scheduler (see [CREATE EVENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-event.html) for the syntax) if it's enabled on your server, or use a cron job as suggested elsewhere

Comment: events is the way to go if you have mysql 5.1 or higher.

Comment: can we use mysql trigger for this issue?

Comment: Maybe, but you'd have to find some table-related trigger to use. Triggers only fire on INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statements. I suppose you could trigger the copy on every INSERT to table A, but that could generate a lot of activity that achieves very little. Whether that's better than an event would have to be decided by the traffic on a live server.

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into tableb select * from tablea;
```

Full documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for something like:

```
CREATE TABLE tableB LIKE tableA;
```

Answer (score 0):

As already said the SQL code for this is "insert into b (select * from A)"

to call this automatically you can write a small PHP-Cronjob, add this to the crontab of your server and let it execute every x min/hour/days (what you need)